# Issue with BorderLayout. java, applet

Tags: java, applet

hi guys i seem to be having a issue with the lay out of my applet, I have a 5 button (cluster) in the applet that are in the top(North) center I would like them to be in the bottom(south) center of the applet, can anyone help get it to the bottom?- the button cluster is fine I just want it to be at the bottom of my applets frame no the top like it currently is (I want to move the buttons cluster to the bottom)...thanks guys

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.applet.*;


  public class moveIt extends Applet implements ActionListener

      {

 private Image cup;
 private Panel Keypad = new Panel();
 public int top = 15;
 public int left = 15;
 private Button Keyarray[] = new Button[5];
 public void init ()
 {
cup=getImage(getDocumentBase(), "cup.gif");
Canvas myCanvas= new Canvas();


 Keyarray[0] = new Button ("Up");
 Keyarray[1] = new Button ("Left");
 Keyarray[2] = new Button ("Down");
 Keyarray[3] = new Button ("Right");
 Keyarray[4] = new Button ("Center");
 setBackground(Color.BLUE);

 Panel frame = new Panel();
 frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 frame.add(myCanvas, BorderLayout.NORTH);
 Keypad.setLayout(new BorderLayout());     
 frame.add(Keypad, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 //Keypad.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


 Keypad.add(Keyarray[0], BorderLayout.NORTH);
 Keypad.add(Keyarray[1], BorderLayout.WEST);
 Keypad.add(Keyarray[2], BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 Keypad.add(Keyarray[3], BorderLayout.EAST);
 Keypad.add(Keyarray[4], BorderLayout.CENTER);

 Keyarray[0].addActionListener(this);
 Keyarray[1].addActionListener(this);
 Keyarray[2].addActionListener(this);
 Keyarray[3].addActionListener(this);
 Keyarray[4].addActionListener(this);


 }//end of method init


 public void paint(Graphics g)


 {

     g.drawImage(cup, left, top, this);

 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
     String arg= e.getActionCommand();

      if (arg.equals("Up"))
            top -= 15;
        if (arg.equals("down"))
            top += 15;
        if (arg.equals("Left"))
            left -= 15;
        if (arg.equals("Right"))
            left += 15;
        if (arg.equals("Center"))
        {
            top=60;
            left=125;
        }

     repaint();



      }//end paint method

   }//end of class
```

Comment: May you elaborate more? I can't seem to grasp where your problem lies.

Comment: @Gliptal I have a group of buttons I want to move to the bottom of my applet... i used the frame.add(Keypad, BorderLayout.SOUTH); but they are in the north, how come?how do i fix it?

Comment: It probably means nothing, but your `Keypad` shouldn't be capitalized. Also, try and putting the `Keypad.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` call before you add `Keypad` to your `frame`.

Comment: @Gliptal just tried that still not working so what its supposed to be doing is the frame has a border layout with the canvas set to north and the keypad set to south , the key pad has its own border lay out with its own components (the buttons in north, south, east, west and center- like a container in a frame container/ a div with divs in a main div) but the buttons are north not south for some reason thats where the issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got your point... here is how I modified init() to have the button in the bottom area.

I also moved canvas to center because, if you have it in NORTH, you can't see it as it is 0x0 size. Anyway I'm not sure this is what you actually want so maybe you will have to move it back to NORTH.

Basically what I did to solve the buttons issue is just removing the Panel frame you had and set BorderLayout manager to the applet.

```
public void init() {
  cup = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "cup.gif");
  Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();

  Keyarray[0] = new Button("Up");
  Keyarray[1] = new Button("Left");
  Keyarray[2] = new Button("Down");
  Keyarray[3] = new Button("Right");
  Keyarray[4] = new Button("Center");
  setBackground(Color.BLUE);

  // I just removed Panel frame and added components directly to applet
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  add(myCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  myCanvas.setBackground(Color.red);
  Keypad.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  add(Keypad, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  // Keypad.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  Keypad.add(Keyarray[0], BorderLayout.NORTH);
  Keypad.add(Keyarray[1], BorderLayout.WEST);
  Keypad.add(Keyarray[2], BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  Keypad.add(Keyarray[3], BorderLayout.EAST);
  Keypad.add(Keyarray[4], BorderLayout.CENTER);

  Keyarray[0].addActionListener(this);
  Keyarray[1].addActionListener(this);
  Keyarray[2].addActionListener(this);
  Keyarray[3].addActionListener(this);
  Keyarray[4].addActionListener(this);

}// end of method init
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: yes with some minor edits it working thanks....             setLayout(new    BorderLayout());
       add(myCanvas, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        Keypad.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         add(Keypad, BorderLayout.SOUTH);